# UCWA Application is going offline even when reporting activity

Tags: skype-for-business, ucwa

We have an UCWA App that runs as part of a ASP.NET Web Application (as a singleton), and we're using a scheduled job which every two minutes performs `reportMyActivity` as per documentation; to maintain the application alive and Online.

What we observe, looking at our server logs, is that the application is anyway regularly being shut down by the server, approximately always in about 20 minutes after it was created. During these 20 minutes `reportMyActivity` returns correctly *204 - NoContent*, after that (when going offline), `reportMyActivity` returns *404 - NotFound* instead.

We're also now dumping every event coming through the event channel, and looking at them I don't see any event or evidence being raised; corresponding with the time when UCWA App is being shut down from the server.

We're targeting an on-premises multi-tenant environment.

Any idea or suggestion?

Comment: I would tend to think that there is either a configuration setting on the server side that is limiting the lifetime of the application to 20 minutes or internal code has changed that if a UCWA application is not active in a conversation it may be cleaning up the resource.  You should look at the duration of the token and convert that to how many minutes it is valid for as well.  If your application is cleaned up after 20 minutes, just re-use the data (culture, endpointId, userAgent) used to create the original application when issuing a POST on /applications and it will recreate the app.

Comment: We don't use conversations. The app is kept alive just to dispatch presence status changes. It doesn't have to do with the oAuth token because when we're in that case we get a 403 (Forbidden), and not 404. We have implemented as well the logic to renew the OAuth token five minutes before it will expire, performing application recreation as you suggest. UCWA App stays correctly online for about 15 minutes, then it stops dispatching presence updates. After few minutes (2-3) reportMyActivity returns 404. If you know more about these server settings I'd appreciate. Thanks for your comment